# Access to fetch at 'API_Gateway_URL' from origin 'S3_host_url' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I know this question has been asked previously but I couldn't find any answer that solves my problem, so please forgive me if it is repetitive.

I have created a Lambda function that reads data from a DynamoDB table. I created an API gateway for this Lambda function.
When I directly hit the url in my browser, I get the expected result. But when I fetch the URL in my react app, I'm getting the below error(I have hosted my react app on S3 bucket with static website hosting)

> Access to fetch at 'API_gateway_url' 
>   from origin 'S3_static_website_endpoint' has been blocked 
>   by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

On searching the web, I found out that I need to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in my Lambda and I have done it, but still I'm getting the same issue.

PS: I'm posting this question after 1 whole day of trial-error and looking at different answers, so if you know the answer please help me!

Lambda function:

```
console.log('function starts');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    function formatResponse(data, code) {
      return { 
        statusCode: code,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"X-Api-Key"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }
    }

    let param = {
        TableName: 'tableName',
        Limit: 100 //maximum result of 100 items
    };

    //Will scan your entire table in dynamoDB and return results.
    dynamoDB.scan(param, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            return formatResponse(data, 400);
        }else{
            return formatResponse(data, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

React app:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: {}
        };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('API_gateway_url');
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            this.setState(
                {
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson
                },
                function () { }
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        let { dataSource } = this.state;
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    {dataSource.Items.map(item => (
                        <div key={item.PlayerId}>
                            <h1>{item.PlayerId}</h1>
                            <li>{item.PlayerName}</li>
                            <li>{item.PlayerPosition}</li>
                            <li>{item.PlayerNationality}</li>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by using the cors package.
Implementation can be found here:
https://epsagon.com/blog/aws-lambda-express-getting-started-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your Lambda is not run for OPTIONS requests (i.e. a "preflight"). You can configure CORS in your API Gateway which should resolve the problem. See [Enabling CORS for a REST API resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found a slightly easier way by using the cors package for node.